# Pushing repo with environment variables

Tags: node.js, git

In my repo on my machine I have a file called `.env`. This contains environment variables for testing as I'm working on the project.

But, when I push to Github I do not want this file included. So I added it to `.gitignore`. I have another file called `.env.sample` that contains empty variables for the user to set.

When the application is installed using `npm install` I have a script that moves this from `.env.sample` to `.env`.

This causes an issue for me because when I'm testing and I run the install it overwrites my original `.env`. Which is normal behaviour, but I can't help but think there's a better way to do this to stop that from happening.

It's a pain because just before I push I have to rename `.env` to `.env.sample` and clear the development variables.

Any idea on how to do this so I don't have to manually rename the file before I push?

Here is the install script from `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js",
    "start": "npm run build && electron .",
    "postinstall": "bash postinstall.sh && mv .env.sample .env",
    "add-cors": "add-cors-to-couchdb"
  },
```

The `postinstall.sh` runs every time install runs to build some software. I could have just put the `mv` inside that, which is what I will probably do.

Comment: *"I have a script that moves this from .env.sample to .env"*. Either this script should run only once, or it should detect the presence of the file and compare dates. It's also frequent to ask in the documentation to users to manually copy and edit the configuration file ([exemple](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/installation.md#fill-the-configuration)).

Comment: To make that question answerable, I feel we should see the install script.

Comment: @DenysSéguret added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to not overwrite the file:

```
"postinstall": "bash postinstall.sh && cp -n .env.sample .env",
```

(note that I propose to use `cp` instead of `mv` so that you don't remove the default file)

Another (frequent) one would be to simply ask the user to do it. It's a light task compared to all the configuration he has to do anyway.